# problems with LongType and FloatType when inserting data into Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, hector

I  insert data into a cassandra data base using Hector,using this code :

```
mutator.addInsertion(key, columnfamily, HFactory
                .createStringColumn(dataproperties.getObjectIDcolumnName(),
                        line.objectid));

mutator.addInsertion(key,columnfamily,
                    HFactory.createColumn(dataproperties.getNumtvaluecolomnname(), java.lang.Float.valueOf(value), StringSerializer.get(), FloatSerializer.get()));
```

numvalue colomn is defined as FloatTYPE

I have no error on code execution,  however  when i chek  data Float value are wrong ( i have this kind of values : C\xb3\x00\x00 when I expect 41.0) 
String data are properly inserted
How can i properly insert numeric data from Hector In order to make correct queries

Thank you.

Comment: @asma can you post column family definition .......

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in your column family definition,try this

```
create column family columnfamily
with column_type = 'Standard' 
and comparator = 'UTF8Type' 
and default_validation_class = 'FloatType' 
and key_validation_class = 'UTF8Type' ;

Insertion(key,columnfamily,
                HFactory.createColumn(dataproperties.getNumtvaluecolomnname(),
java.lang.Float.valueOf(value), StringSerializer.get(),
me.prettyprint.cassandra.serializers.FloatSerializer.FloatSerializer.get()));
```

and fetching data

```
SliceQuery<String,String,byte[]> sliceQuery = HFactory.createSliceQuery(keyspace, se, se,BytesArraySerializer.get());
sliceQuery.setColumnFamily("columnfamily");
        sliceQuery.setKey(key);
        sliceQuery.setRange(null,null,true,10);
        List<HColumn<String,byte[]>> hcolumns = sliceQuery.execute().get()
                .getColumns();
        for (HColumn<String, byte[]> hcolumn : hcolumns){
            System.out.println("Name "+hcolumn.getName());
        System.out.println("Value"+
        FloatSerializer.get().fromBytes(hcolumn.getValue()));
        }
```

**FloatSerializer.get().fromBytes(hcolumn.getValue())** convert value byte array to float

Comment: this is my colomn family definition

Comment: create colmn family entries 

   WITH comparator = UTF8Type

   AND key_validation_class=UTF8Type

AND column_metadata = [
{column_name: id , validation_class: UTF8Type}
{column_name: objectid, validation_class: UTF8Type, index_type: KEYS}
{column_name: time, validation_class: LongType,index_type: KEYS}
{column_name: label, validation_class: UTF8Type, index_type: KEYS}
{column_name: text_val, validation_class: UTF8Type, index_type: KEYS}
{column_name: num_val, validation_class: FloatType, index_type: KEYS}
];

Comment: when I tried to set default validation class to floatType i can't insert string values any more !! I really don't know what to do

Comment: @asma if you not declare default_validation class then cassandra store a value in byte array.i add the code how to fetch byte array value.

Comment: thanks AMit i solved the problem , it was on dataproperties.getNumtvaluecolomnname()